# Get webpage content in asp using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I want to fill my MultiLine textbox from webpage's this is my code:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(urltxt.Text.Trim());
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
string html = String.Empty;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
{
    html = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
var htmlBody = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
valuetxt.Text = htmlBody.InnerText;
```

This code is working fine for some url but for some url (https) this gave me an error:

> Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\www.justdial.com

or:

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance, sorry for my bad English.

Comment: In what of these lines are the exceptions comming from?

Comment: WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

Comment: Can you give examples of the Urls you're trying to hit.  Also you're not telling `WebRequest` that it's a HTTPS conntection.  Look at this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560804/how-do-i-use-webrequest-to-access-an-ssl-encrypted-site-using-https

Comment: I'm trying "https://www.justdial.com/Chandigarh/Packers-Movers/nct-10348289". Only www.justdial.com website give me an error. I tried some of online tools they also give me invalid url error. I think this is not my code problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your address doesn't have *http://* or *https://* at the beginning; in the `urltxt` variable and you get error because of relative addressing.

Comment: Thanks. You solved my one problem "Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\...", But in https url i got  "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden"

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a proxy? Even on open internet, depending on your network configuration, you might need to set credentials in your connection before requesting.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(urltxt.Text.Trim());
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `UserAgent` to your request to connect *https* properly:

```
request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36";
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38336695/2040375)