# HttpClient not connecting to URL from UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, dotnet-httpclient

First, I must admit that I'm not certain whether I should be using Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient or System.Net.Http.HttpClient.  It seems Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient is the way to go for UWP, but I've tried both without success.

From the URL, I expect to receive a JSON object.  When I copy and paste the URL into a browser, I can see the JSON object just fine.  If I leave the cache alone after connecting with a browser, the UWP has no problem reading from the cache.  I used my same code to connect to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 and was able to retrieve the JSON object from there without any issues.  Here's my basic attempt:

```
async void Connect()
    {
        using (Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(@"https://www.nottheactualdomainname.com/?api=software-api&email=xxxx@xxxx.com&licence_key=xxxx&request=status&product_id=xxxxinstance=20181218215300");
            Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage();
            string httpResponseBody = "";

            try
            {
                httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
                httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                httpResponseBody = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (JsonObject.TryParse(httpResponseBody, out JsonObject keyValuePairs))
                {
                    //handle JSON object
                }
                else
                {
                    //didn't recieve JSON object
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                httpResponseBody = "Error: " + ex.HResult.ToString("X") + " Message: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried including this at various points (i.e. before the using statement, right before initializing httpResponse, and right before the try statement):

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

As well as this (knowing that I would only able to do this while debugging):

```
//for debugging ONLY; not safe for production
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

Sometimes I get this error:

Error: 80131500 Message: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 ().

And sometiemes I get this error:

Error: 80190193 Message: Forbidden (403).

Or both.  I have tried this with both Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient and System.Net.Http.HttpClient.

I will eventually need to make sure that my URL includes appropriate credentials for the server.  However, incorrect credentials should just return a JSON with error information, and I'm not getting that.  I can connect to https://www.nottheactualdomainname.com.  What should I check next?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38336703/10243001)

I was able to use the browser developer tools to look at the request headers.  Then I added this:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36");
```